# Adaptec 2610 RAID 1 - status 'Impacted'

Tags: raid, adaptec

I have created a second array using the 2nd and 3rd disks in the bay and ran through the process - its build but now showing a status of 'impacted'.

How can i get this to 'optimal'?

Thanks in advance
A

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Presumably you mean a 21610sa, not the 2610 as that was an MCA-to-MFM/ESDI controller from back when 'thirtysomething' was a cool show :)

From the 21610sa manual;

"An impacted array is one which has been created, but for some reason the initial build operation did not complete. All member drives are present and operational, and all data written to the array is protected. To optimize the array, run a Verify with Fix task."

Hope this helps.